# EKS cluster deployment always fails at Custom::AWSCDK-EKS-KubernetesResource with ETIMEDOUT

Tags: amazon-eks, aws-cdk

Our AWS account has only one VPC. The VPC and the subnets in them are provisioned outside of CDK scope. Our corporate data center connectivity and outbound https internet traffic is enabled through a transit gateway. There is no https proxy server required or available in this deployment.

I'm trying to create an EKS cluster utilizing the existing VPC and subnets in the following way.

```
import { aws_ec2, aws_eks, Stack, StackProps } from "aws-cdk-lib";
import { Construct } from "constructs";

export class MyStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    // Find VPC
    const existingVpc = aws_ec2.Vpc.fromLookup(this, "ExistingVPC", {
      tags: {
        Name: "ExistingVPCTag",
      },
    });

    // and subnets
    const az1Subnet = aws_ec2.Subnet.fromSubnetId(
      this,
      "az1Subnet",
      "subnet-abc"
    );
    const az2Subnet = aws_ec2.Subnet.fromSubnetId(
      this,
      "az2Subnet",
      "subnet-xyz"
    );

    // Due to
    //   https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/10341
    //   https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/19425
    //
    // have to comment all the following code and run cdk synth
    // once to initialize and populate vpc info in cdk.context.json

    const cluster = new aws_eks.Cluster(this, "MyCluster", {
      clusterName: "my-cluster",
      defaultCapacity: 0,
      endpointAccess: aws_eks.EndpointAccess.PRIVATE,
      version: aws_eks.KubernetesVersion.V1_21,
      vpc: existingVpc,
      vpcSubnets: [
        {
          subnets: [az1Subnet, az2Subnet],
        },
      ],
    });
  }
}
```

The `cdk.context.json` identifies the VPC and configuration as `Isolated`. As I mentioned, this is not truly isolated. Internet access is available, but through transit gateway.

```
{
  "vpc-provider:account=1234567890:filter.tag:Name=ExistingVPCTag:region=us-west-2:returnAsymmetricSubnets=true": {
    "vpcId": "vpc-abcdefgh",
    "vpcCidrBlock": "10.11.12.0/23",
    "availabilityZones": [],
    "subnetGroups": [
      {
        "name": "Isolated",
        "type": "Isolated",
        "subnets": [
          {
```

I can see the cluster creation itself is successful.

```
MyStack |  7/12 | 3:35:10 pm | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | Custom::AWSCDK-EKS-Cluster            | Cluster/Resource/Resource/Default (Cluster9EE0221C) 
 7/12 Currently in progress: MyStack, Cluster9EE0221C
MyStack |  7/12 | 3:46:30 pm | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | Custom::AWSCDK-EKS-Cluster            | Cluster/Resource/Resource/Default (Cluster9EE0221C) Resource creation Initiated
MyStack |  8/12 | 3:46:30 pm | CREATE_COMPLETE      | Custom::AWSCDK-EKS-Cluster            | Cluster/Resource/Resource/Default (Cluster9EE0221C) 
MyStack |  8/12 | 3:46:33 pm | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::SSM::Parameter                   | Cluster/KubectlReadyBarrier (ClusterKubectlReadyBarrier200052AF) 
MyStack |  8/12 | 3:46:33 pm | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack            | @aws-cdk--aws-eks.KubectlProvider.NestedStack/@aws-cdk--aws-eks.KubectlProvider.NestedStackResource (awscdkawseksKubectlProviderNestedStackawscdkawseksKubectlProviderNestedStackResourceA7AEBA6B) 
MyStack |  8/12 | 3:46:34 pm | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::CloudFormation::Stack            | @aws-cdk--aws-eks.KubectlProvider.NestedStack/@aws-cdk--aws-eks.KubectlProvider.NestedStackResource (awscdkawseksKubectlProviderNestedStackawscdkawseksKubectlProviderNestedStackResourceA7AEBA6B) Resource creation Initiated
MyStack |  8/12 | 3:46:34 pm | CREATE_IN_PROGRESS   | AWS::SSM::Parameter                   | Cluster/KubectlReadyBarrier (ClusterKubectlReadyBarrier200052AF) Resource creation Initiated
MyStack |  9/12 | 3:46:35 pm | CREATE_COMPLETE      | AWS::SSM::Parameter                   | Cluster/KubectlReadyBarrier (ClusterKubectlReadyBarrier200052AF)
```

However the CloudFormation deployment fails with this error, after EKS cluster etc is created.

```
MyStack | 10/12 | 4:00:48 pm | CREATE_FAILED        | Custom::AWSCDK-EKS-KubernetesResource | Cluster/AwsAuth/manifest/Resource/Default (ClusterAwsAuthmanifestFE51F8AE) Received response status [FAILED] from custom resource. Message returned: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 34.223.18.133:443
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1159:16) (RequestId: bf13e37a-c6ec-432c-9147-cfc6f6ba8007)
```

The IP indicated is not the k8s API endpoint, and I can't figure out what service is that. I've tried specifying PRIVATE, PUBLIC, PUBLIC_AND_PRIVATE and had no success. The nearest of the Github issues I could relate with it is this https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/13080. There is a trailing comment in the issue mentioning of S3 bucket access, but I verified the endpoint policy associated to the VPC as allowing all. As the defect submitter mentioned, changing `defaultCapacity` does not help, instead I get additional failures that the provisioned worker nodes could not join the cluster.

What exactly is happening here ?

Comment: I'm having the same problem right now, using similar config and Private Eks endpoint. Even tried changing the subnets from private_isolated to private with egress. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @CodigoMorsa My case happened to be that there really was no internet routing created by IT through the transit gateway for the subnets designated for EKS. I hadn't really verified it because there was no EC2 instance deployed into that subnet, where I could quickly check. Once the internet connectivity was established, I could deploy it.